# function for finding last item less-than-or-equal to, like lower_bound

Tags: c++, binary-search, lower-bound

Is there a function in  that uses binary search, like `lower_bound` but that returns the *last* item *less-than-or-equal-to* according to a given predicate?

`lower_bound` is defined to:

> Finds the position of the *first* element in an ordered range that has a value *greater than or equivalent to* a specified value, where the ordering criterion may be specified by a binary predicate.

and `upper_bound`:

> Finds the position of the *first* element in an ordered range that has a value that is *greater than* a specified value, where the ordering criterion may be specified by a binary predicate.

Specifically, I have a container of time ordered events and for a given time I want to find the last item that came before or at that point.  Can I achieve this with some combination of upper/lower bound, reverse iterators and using `std::greater` or `std::greater_equal` ?

EDIT: 
A tweak was needed to user763305's suggestion to cope with if you ask for a point before the start of the array:

```
iterator it=upper_bound(begin(), end(), val, LessThanFunction());
if (it!=begin()) {
  it--; // not at end of array so rewind to previous item
} else {
  it=end(); // no items before this point, so return end()
}
return it;
```

Comment: Just a warning about using a different comparator -- you *must* use the same comparator (or a logically equivalent one) to the one the range was sorted with, otherwise the binary search algorithms have undefined behavior. So if you wanted to use `std::greater` you'd first have to either reverse the range or use a reverse iterator over it. And you can't ever use `std::greater_equal` as a comparator because it is not a strict weak order.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In a sorted container, the last element that is less than or equivalent to `x`, is the element before the first element that is greater than `x`.

Thus you can call `std::upper_bound`, and decrement the returned iterator once.
(Before decrementing, you must of course check that it is not the begin iterator; if it is, then there are no elements that are less than or equivalent to `x`.)

Comment: Thanks - I should have mentioned that this is similar to what I have already, though I used lower_bound which means I had to perform more checks.  Using upper_bound does simplify this somewhat.  I was hoping though that an incantation such as `lower_bound(rbegin(), rend(), value, std::greater())` would do what I needed in one go

Comment: @the_mandrill: I think that works, but it returns a reverse iterator, which you'd presumably then have to convert to a normal iterator. Personally I find such conversions more confusing than decrementing an iterator would be :-)

Comment: Hmm, just found that this isn't quite enough because it fails in the case that you are looking for a point before the start of the array. I've added the solution to the question

Comment: Yes, sorry, you did mention about begin(), I just wanted to make it explicit that you need to return end() in that particular case.

Comment: @Steve: Not like that's particularly complicated - `return revit == rend()? end() : revit.base();`. I actually find this to be clearer, since you compare if the iterator doesn't exist (off the end) with `rend()`.

Comment: @Xeo: revit will point to element the_mandrill is interested in, but revit.base() will point to the element after, so it has to be return revit == rend()? end() : --revit.base();

Comment: Like I said, I find it confusing. You end up with similar-looking code to doing it the way in the answer, but it's harder to convince myself whether it's correct.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: I agree with that. It is perfectly logical, but also perfectly confusing. One of the cases where C++ is too logical for its own good. I almost never use C++ reverse iterators in production code.

Comment: I'm happy to use them provided that I'm only using reverse iterators -- printing out a vector backwards is no problem. I try to avoid switching back and forth between reverse and normal iterators "at the same point". When absolutely necessary you can write helper functions to distinguish between the two different kinds of "at the same point" -- "inserts at the same place" vs. "dereferences to the same element". As far as I can tell, the whole system was designed by people who enjoy debugging off-by-one errors ;-)

Answer (score 14):

I have test your reverse iterator solution, it is correct.

Given `v` is sorted by '<'

Find last element less than x:

```
auto iter = std::upper_bound(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), x, std::greater<int>());
if(iter == v.rend())
    std::cout<<"no found";
else
    std::cout<<*iter;
```

Find last element less than equal x:

```
auto iter = std::lower_bound(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), x, std::greater<int>());
if(iter == v.rend())
    std::cout<<"no found";
else
    std::cout<<*iter;
```

This is better than `iter -= 1` version

Comment: elegant solution!

Comment: It returns `reverse_iterator`, and if we need a normal iterator, we need to call `::base` method. It will then return what normal UB/LB would return. And then need to decrement iterator by one.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a wrapper function around upper_bound which returns the largest number in a container or array which is less than or equal to a given value:

```
template <class ForwardIterator, class T>
  ForwardIterator largest_less_than_or_equal_to ( ForwardIterator first, 
                                                  ForwardIterator last,
                                                  const T& value)
{
  ForwardIterator upperb = upper_bound(first, last, value);

  // First element is >, so none are <=
  if(upperb == first)
    return NULL;

  // All elements are <=, so return the largest.
  if(upperb == last)
    return --upperb;

  return upperb - 1;
}
```

For a better explanation of what this is doing and how to use this function, check out:

[C++ STL — Find last number less than or equal to a given element in an array or container](http://web.archive.org/web/20121120125603/http://www.swageroo.com/wordpress/c-stl-find-last-number-less-than-or-equal-to-a-given-element-in-an-array-or-container/)

Comment: return NULL really does not compile. And at the end it returns --upperb or upperb - 1. This basically means the same so why not just --upperb.

Answer (score 2):

`std::prev`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, char> m{{2, 'a'}, {4, 'b'}, {6, 'c'}, {8, 'd'}, {10, 'e'}};

    int num = 3;
    auto it = m.upper_bound(num);
    auto pv = std::prev(it);

    std::cout << "upper bound of " << num << ": "
        << it->first << ", " << it->second << '\n';
    std::cout << "lower than or equal of " << num << ": "
        << pv->first << ", " << pv->second << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
upper bound of 3: 4, b
lower than or equal than 3: 2, a
```