# An algorithm like lower_bound(), but another

Tags: c++, algorithm

There is a `upper_bound()`, returns an iterator to the first element that is **greater** than val.

There is a `lower_bound()`, returns an iterator to the first element that is **not less** than val.

Is there an algorithm that returns an iterator to the first element that is **not greater** than val, or I have to reinvent the wheel?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6 };

    auto lower = std::lower_bound(data.begin(), data.end(), 4, [](int x, int y) {return x > y;});

    cout << *lower ;
}
```

Output: 1, expexted 3

Note that another predicate like `std::greater<>` doesn't work.

Comment: How about using a different predicate for `lower_bound`, like `std::greater<>`?

Comment: using `reverse_iterator`...

Comment: or `upper_bound(..) - 1`

Comment: @Jarod42, It seems good, thank you

Comment: @Jarod42 `upper_bound()` works with forward iterators so in some cases that may not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<algorithm> function for finding last item less-than-or-equal to, like lower\_bound](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989731/algorithm-function-for-finding-last-item-less-than-or-equal-to-like-lower-bou)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the predicate as in your code, but traverse it in reverse order with `rbegin` and `rend`

Answer (score 1):

My two bits, you forgot to sort in descending order.

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> data = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6 };

    int wanted {4};
    sort(begin(data), end(data), greater<int>());
    auto bound =  upper_bound(begin(data), end(data), wanted, greater<int>());
    cout << "val with upper_bound: " << *bound << endl;


}

result:  val with upper_bound: 3
```

or one step below with partition_point:

```
template <typename T>
struct greater_than {
    T x;
    bool operator()(const T& y) { return y > x; }
};

int main() 
{
 ...
 auto p_point = partition_point(begin(data), end(data),
                               greater_than<int>{wanted});

 cout << "val with partition_point: " << *p_point << endl;
// val with partition_point: 3
```